# Textile plug-in throwing PHP errors RE preg_replace /e modifier

Tags: plugin, php-errors

I'm using the Textile plug-in on a new project and it's spawning PHP errors all over the place and complaining thusly:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: 8192
>
> Message: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead
>
> Filename: textile/pi.textile.php
>
> Line Number: 918

Not one I've run into before but this is occurring in my local dev env on a new MacBook so it's a fresh install of MAMP running PHP 5.5.3.

Any ideas???

**Update:** I only see the PHP error in the front end templates when logged in as Admin.

The function generating the error is 'footNoteRef':

```
function footnoteRef($text)
{
    return preg_replace('/(?<=\S)\[([0-9]+)\](\s)?/Ue',
        '$this->footnoteID(\'\1\',\'\2\')', $text);
}
```

:)

Comment: As I just tweeted to you - could you post the function where this is occurring.

Comment: There you go. It's 'footnoteRef' that's throwing the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to https://www.php.net/preg_replace , the /e modifier was removed in PHP 5.5.0 . If you downgrade PHP to pre-5.5.0, then the error will go away. Alternatively, in your config.php file set error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED); to hide deprecated warnings.

Alternatively, upgrade Textile - but it looks like http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/textile-editor-helper-teh hasn't been upgraded in some time.

=== Added after you posted the code ==

Try changing

```
function footnoteRef($text)
{
    return preg_replace('/(?<=\S)\[([0-9]+)\](\s)?/Ue',
        '$this->footnoteID(\'\1\',\'\2\')', $text);
}
```

to (untested)

```
function footnoteRef($text)
{
    return preg_replace_callback('/(?<=\S)\[([0-9]+)\](\s)?/U',
function ($matches) {
            return $this->footnoteID($matches[1],$matches[2]);
        },
         $text);
}
```

Comment: Hoorah, this worked out the box. Thanks Richy.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you remove everything from the function as it is and replace it with the following:

```
preg_replace_callback('/(?<=\S)\[([0-9]+)\](\s)?/U',
                   create_function('$matches','return $this->footnoteID($matches[1],$matches[2])'), $text);
```

This is totally untested, but I *think* it's right. No doubt if it's not, someone will chime in - Regular Expressions are not my forte.

Comment: Didn't work for me, I got another PHP error but thanks anyway. Pretty sure it's just missing a character here or there. :)

Comment: Whats the error?

Answer (score 0):

after upgrading to php 7.3 you will likely see a similar error related to textile compilation

```
preg_replace_callback(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 184
user/addons/textile/pi.textile.php, line 628
```

this is explained quite well in this stackoverflow thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56551371/11512584

> PHP PCRE engine migrates to PCRE2, and the PCRElibrary version used in
> PHP 7.3 is 10.32, and that is where Backward Incompatible Changes
> originate from

on line 615 column 38 of pi.textile.php there was an unescaped hyphen, adding  a backslash before this hyphen was enough to resolve the compilation error in my case (expression engine 5.4.2, using Textile plugin for ExpressionEngine 2.x)

diff:

```
615c615
<       $qtags = array('\*\*','\*','\?\?','\-','__','_','%','\+','~','\^');
---
>       $qtags = array('\*\*','\*','\?\?','-','__','_','%','\+','~','\^');
```